# Como simular um usuário logado em uma aplicação com Demoiselle 2.4.2?

Tags: java, demoiselle, junit

Tenho uma aplicação **Demoiselle 2.4.2** já em funcionamento que necessita utilizar o `SecurityContext` para obter o `User` atualmente logado e tomar algumas decisões. O momento agora é escrever os testes unitários usando **JUnit 4** para esta aplicação (não foram feitos na gênese da aplicação, mas queremos fazer agora). Neste momento surge o problema de não existir processo de *logon* que anteceda a execução dos casos de teste.

Por qual técnica é possível simular o processo de *logon*, de forma que quando instâncias de `SecurityContext` forem injetadas ao longo dos *controllers* da aplicação (**não** nos casos de teste), estes respondam com o usuário que eu precisar?

**Atualização 1**

Para tornar a situação mais fácil de entender, segue código da classe que implementa o teste unitário:

```
@RunWith(DemoiselleRunner.class)
public class CaixaOperacaoTests {

    @Inject
    static private Credentials credentials;

    @Inject
    private CaixaOperacaoBC caixaOperacao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        credentials.setUsername("meususario");
        credentials.setPassword("minhasenha");
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldAbrirCaixaComUsuarioLogado() {
        // Arrange
        BigDecimal valorAbertura = new BigDecimal(10.50);

        // Act
        CaixaSessao sessao = caixaOperacao.abrirCaixa(valorAbertura, null);

        // Assert
        assertThat(sessao, notNullValue());
    }
}
```

O problema ocorre antes mesmo de o teste unitário iniciar, durante a injeção de `caixaOperacao`, pois esta instância depende da credencial existente em uma classe auxiliar que temos chamada `SecurityServices`, que é injetada em `CaixaOperacaoBC`.

Segue o código de `SecurityServices´:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class SecurityServices {
    @Inject
    SecurityContext securityContext;
    @Inject
    PessoaBC pessoaBC;

    public Long idPessoaFisicaDoUsuarioLogado(){
        Long idPessoa = (Long) securityContext.getUser().getAttribute(UsuarioSession.Fields.PESSOA_ID);
        return idPessoa;
    }

    public Pessoa pessoaFisicaDoUsuarioLogado(){
        Long idPessoa = idPessoaFisicaDoUsuarioLogado();
        return pessoaBC.load(idPessoa);
    }

    SecurityContext getContext() {
        return securityContext;
    }
}
```

Notar que no método `idPessoaFisicaDoUsuarioLogado()` existe o uso de `securityContext`, que tem valor. No entanto, o método `getUser()` retorna `null` de onde advém todos os meus problemas.

Naturalmente, a definição da credencial não pode ocorrer na classe do teste unitário, tem que ocorrer antes, mas onde?

Comment: Ola, já chegou a olhar o doc? http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/framework/reference/2.5.0-RC1/html/security.html#d0e2765

Answer (score 0):

O Demoiselle tem um esquema de autenticação e autorização muito eficaz.
Aconselho você verificar o doc, como você usa a versão 2.4.2, o link é o seguinte:

[Desmoiselle - Segurança](http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/framework/reference/2.4.2/html/security.html)

De atenção a injeção da seguinte classe:

```
    @Inject
    private Credentials credentials;
```

Nela você pode colocar o usuário logado e acessar de qualquer lugar do sistema apenas com a injeção dessa classe.

Aqui na empresa utilizamos a estrategia de Autenticação e Autorização do Demoiselle, mas criamos a nossa própria classe Credenciais com escopo de seção.

Mas verifique o manual, lá você encontrará tudo, e qualquer dúvida comenta ai!

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta para fornecer mais dados. Acredito que a dica seja a correta, mas me falta ainda algum detalhe para solucionar definitivamente o problema.

Comment: E então rapaz, conseguiu solucionar o problema?

Comment: Desculpe pela demora em responder. Consegui resolver, mas não utilizando o mecanismo sugerido. Interferi na credencial ativa de outra forma porque nossas classes implementam um serviço auxiliar de segurança.